# NSCollectionView outlet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have created an outlet from a `NSCollectionView` . However during runtime, it is logged as type `NSScrollView`. Because of this, I am not able to set the content.

I made sure that I ctrl+dragged from the collection view and not the top level scroll view.

What is the problem here?

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSCollectionView *collectionView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *scrollView;
```

Edit : Also, when I do

```
NSLog([self.scrollView description]);
NSLog([self.collectionView description]);
```

or just

```
NSLog([self.collectionView description]);
```

I get same logs(description of scrollview).

Comment: Show the property declaration - and are you REAlLY sure you did select the collectionView??

Comment: Yeah.. first thing I checked when i had this problem..

Comment: When you add a `NSCollectionView` within Interface Builder you'll get a `NSScrollView` as the base.